# Flutter: Create Horizontal Multiple Dialog Cards like Google Local Guide

Tags: flutter, dialog, card

If we do a place review on Google Map, there is a **dialog**.  A dialog will automatically go to the next dialog, if we have selected the Button at the bottom of the dialog.  How do I create a *large number of dialog cards* like this using Flutter?

[image]

Comment: Can you include what you’ve tried so far? And an attachment of your desire output?

Comment: Seems like the full-screen dialog with the horizontal list view or pages. Can you add what you have done ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I've tried creating, Dialogs inside Dialogs... But the previous dialog still exists, and can't bring up the horizontal scrollview dialog effect.

Comment: You can run my snippet, If you are having nested dialog, you need to pop from 1st dialog then show the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any widget on `showDialog` builder. This will provide you the idea

```dart
class DTEst extends StatelessWidget {
  const DTEst({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<void> _showDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return Material(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.4),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: PageView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Center(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: constraints.maxHeight *
                                    .5, //you can have your custom
                                width: constraints.maxWidth * .8,
                                child: Card(
                                  child: Text("item $index"),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 50,
                              ),
                              Text("custom item $index"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _showDialog(context);
          },
          child: Text("show Dialog"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Include more decoration and inner can have different stack or can be used Transform widget for shifting icon.

Comment: Is there something I am missing here